# How is the time complexity O(n)?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to solve the following question from [LeetCode.com](https://leetcode.com/problems/daily-temperatures/description/):

> Given a list of daily temperatures, produce a list that, for each day in the input, tells you how many days you would have to wait until a warmer temperature. If there is no future day for which this is possible, put 0 instead.  If input is: `[73, 74, 75, 71, 69, 72, 76, 73]`, then the output should be: `[1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0]`.

The working code can be given as below:

```
class Solution {
public:

    vector<int> dailyTemperatures(vector<int>& temperatures) {
        stack<int> s;
        vector<int> result(temperatures.size(),0);

        for(int i=0; i<(int)temperatures.size(); i++) {
            while(!s.empty() && temperatures[i]>temperatures[s.top()]) {
                int idx = s.top();
                s.pop();
                result[idx] = i-idx;
            }
            s.push(i);
        }

        return result;
    }
};
```

As per the [solutions](https://leetcode.com/problems/daily-temperatures/solution/#approach-2-stack-accepted), the time complexity of the above snippet is `O(n)`.  How?  If we consider the worst case input: `[75, 71, 69, 72, 76]`, then wouldn't the time complexity be O(n^2), because we would be inserting *almost* all the elements into the stack `s` and then popping them all later, when we encounter `76`?  Basically, because, if I understand correctly, we are visiting *almost* all the elements twice?

Could someone please explain?  Thanks.

Edit:  Looks like my statement _"we are visiting *almost* all the elements twice"_ is implying the incorrect meaning.  I know the difference between `O(n+n)` and `O(n^2)`.  Here, I think it should be `O(n^2)` because, for a given `i` (`i=4`), we `pop()` all the elements from the stack, in the worst case.

Comment: `if I understand correctly, we are visiting almost all the elements twice` which is O(2n) which is basically O(n)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, I meant to say, _twice_ but not one after the other - simultaneously.

Comment: Interesting.  Why `-1`? If it is so for the earlier, 'invalid comment', then _that_ comment was invalid and so has been deleted!

Comment: @user6490375 It seems you need to get a better understanding of that Big-O notation first. I didn't downvote, but most probably anyone doesn't like your lack of research. Also online code judge questions aren't very welcome here mostly.

Comment: How did you get from "visiting all elements twice" to `O(n^2)`? You would have the latter if you were visiting every element `n` times.

Comment: The values on the stack are the indices of `temperatures`. Every index is pushed and popped at most once. No matter how you slice it, there are never more than O(n) stack operations in total.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, yes, I get that.  But in the worst case example `[75, 71, 69, 72, 76]`, aren't we popping all the values from the stack that we had pushed earlier?

Comment: And that's significant because...? How many calls to `push` and `pop`, total, does the program make in this case? There are exactly `n` calls to `push`, and by definition there can't possibly be more calls to `pop` than to `push`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, so for `i=0` to `i=3`, it always `push`es into the stack, and then for `i=4`, it `pop()`s out all the elements from it.

Comment: Right. But again, so what? Does this program make order of 25 pushes and pops for these 5 elements?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, okay.. So I got your point somewhat.  It `pop()`s out all the elements only for one value of `i`; had it been doing so for all `i`s, then the complexity would have been `O(n^2)`.  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @user6490375 No. It cannot pop more elements than were pushed, and it only pushes `n` elements total.

Comment: yes, the "pop" will "stick" across further `i`, so each value pushed into stack is popped just once (per whole run, not per i). It doesn't matter if particular `i` will pop from stack no item, two items, or all items, because that just makes other `i` have to do more/less work, to balance it out in the end toward n-times push, n-times pop, n-times+few-more(+n in total) compare with top of stack, so something like 4\*n is upper limit of operations. = O(n).

Comment: @Ped7g, thank you.  Your comment was very helpful for me to understand it.  If you convert it into an answer, I would be glad to accept it.  Thanks.

Comment: If you double the size of N do you do approximately twice the work? If so you you have O(N). If you double the size of N and you do exponentially more work then you have O(N*N) or worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's O(n) only, because...

> Here, I think it should be O(n^2) because, for a given i (i=4), we pop() all the elements from the stack, in the worst case.

while this is true for i=4, the `pop` of the stack "sticks" (affects stack content) across whole run, it's not "per `i`", and across whole run there's only N elements pushed to the stack ever, so at most N elements can be popped back (you can't pop something not pushed into it). In your case the `i = {0, .., 3}` were "starving" - just failing the `pop` test - and doing only `push` operation, saving enough operations to justify the `i=4` `pop` operations mayhem, to make it still upper-bounded as O(N) in total.

It doesn't matter whether particular `i` pops no element, one element, two elements, or N elements from the stack, because it just makes the remaining amount of work (remaining content of stack) bigger/smaller for remaining `i` values, totalling on the at-most-N-times `pop` operations in any case. Thus it's not NxN, but N+N.

It would be NxN in case the stack would be independent for each `i`, and having some chance to grow to N-ish size for each `i`, then this would be O(N<sup>2</sup>), but that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem tells that temperature is between [30, 100]. 
So, `temperatures.size()` will not be greater than 71.
Then we can assume that one loop has constant iterations.
Just one will "count", so, O(n).

By the constant loop, it will never show a polynomial behavior.

Comment: This is nicely different point of view, noticing the data constraints playing role in this case too, but the algorithm itself is O(N) even in general any-temperature-range situation. Still I missed this, so ty. :)